# issue with date picker

Tags: ios, iphone, datepicker

I am working with UIDate picker and working well with it. I am using this only to get the time not the date. And i am getting the time on the label but when i am converting this time string to the NSDate type it is showing me wrong output. The output shown is as below.
     1999-12-31 23:30:00 
But it should be 06:45 PM. Can any body please locate my error.

The code i am using is as below.

```
- (void)showPicker:(NSDate *)date
{
    actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the Time" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"DONE" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    pickdate = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:[actionsheet bounds]];
    pickdate.hidden = NO;
    pickdate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    pickdate.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    [pickdate addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionsheet addSubview:pickdate];
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];
    CGRect pickerRect = pickdate.bounds;
    pickerRect.origin.y = -90;
    pickdate.bounds = pickerRect;
    [pickdate setDate:date animated: YES];
 }

 - (IBAction)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"I Am Changing the values");
    df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    timelbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:pickdate.date]];
   NSLog(@"Picker MOde IS %@",df );
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (toggleswitch.on)
        {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"]; // depends on 12(hh) or 24(HH)

            yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timelbl.text];

            [self showPicker:yourDate];
            NSLog(@"YOUR DATE: %@", yourDate);
        }
}
```

Comment: it is because nsdate is showing output in GMT timezone and when you convert it to string using dateformatter then it is showing in your device's local timezone. i.e I am testing from india and time in india is suppose 01/01/2012 5:35:00 AM then when I print date then it shows 01/01/2012 00:05:00 because IST = GMT+5:30.

Comment: @Pratik so what should be the suitable code to resolve this??

Comment: you can can set timezone in nsdateformatter @"GMT" so both are shown same or try with set your device timezone like **[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];**

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *date=[[NSDate alloc]init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@:%@",theDate,theTime);
```

Comment: thanx dheerendra but where should i keep  this in  my  code above . . . . .